# git ps1 is very slow in GNU-Screen

Tags: git, ubuntu, gnu-screen, ps1

I have my custom PS1 on my virtual machine ( *Vagrant / ubuntu-13.10* ), which works perfectly when I ssh to the machine.

But when I run GNU-Screen to have multiple screens I loose that, which is normal (as ~/.bash_profile is not being called at Screen's start-up).

But interesting enough there is no `$(__git_ps1)` available. 
When I execute:

```
echo $(__git_ps1)
```

It takes a while (30-40 seconds) and even when I force exit it with ctrl+c I get the following:

```
 tail: : invalid number of lines
```

But it would eventually print out `(master)` on a blank screen.

So I though it might be an issue with `git-prompt`, but even if I run:

```
source /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt
```

which runs successfully, it is still the same case and if I run `echo $(__git_ps1)` it would take 30 seconds before it prints `(master)`.

Any ideas what could have possibly be going wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried running __git_ps1 on its own with no $()? It could be it's waiting for some input or something which you can't tell because of the $() subshell

Comment: It's exactly the same case for `__git_ps1`. It takes a while and then prints out the following on a blank screen:
tail: : invalid number of lines
 (master)vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant$